# Unable to list SMS using cordova plugin in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have tried using the plugin provided in the below link

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms?files=1

I'm getting an error SMS is not defined

Below is my controller code

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
  .controller('SMSCtrl', function($scope ,$ionicPopup ) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.SMSlist = function() {
      console.log("Button click");
      var filter = {
        box : 'inbox', //inbox, sent, draft
        //following 4 filters should not be applied together, they are OR relationship
        read :1, //0 for unread and 1 for already
        // _id: 1234, //specify the msg id
        // body : 'This is a test SMS' , //content to match
        // address: '+9731151243';

        indexFrom : 0,
        maxCount : 10,

      };   
      if(SMS) SMS.listSMS(filter,function(data){
        if(Array.isArray(data)){
          var sms = data[i];
          console.log(sms);
          $scope.article = sms;
      }
    }, function(err) {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Reading Failed!',
        template: 'Read Failed'
      });
    })
  }
})
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that *deviceReady* has fired before you try to execute that code? You can most easily check that by using *alert();* in two places: on *deviceReady* handler and right before the `if (SMS)`. This way you see which is done first.

Comment: Seems to be I have not initialized the third party plugins but not sure how to initialize. I have inserted the following code in app.js in the run function                                                      .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       var telephoneNumber = window.plugins.sms;
         sms.get(function(result) {
        //result
         }, function() {
          //error
       });
       });
       });

Comment: So the *deviceReady* fires before the `if (SMS)`? In that case, are you using [Cordova CLI](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) or [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) to build your app?

Comment: I'm using Cordova CLI

Comment: I assume you have done `cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.sms` then, right? Are the other plugins working correctly? Also, are you using emulator or real device to test it? And which platform (iOS, Android, WP, other)?

Comment: Yes. I have added the plugin to my project. I have used Camera Plugin and it worked in my Android mobile phone. Please help in initialing this third party plugin to my Ionic

Comment: It should be installed with just that command I gave you. After that the _SMS_ variable should be declared to point into the plugin. There is an example [here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/blob/master/test/index.html) that uses it just like that. Only thing that should be able to go wrong is that the _deviceReady_ isn't fired beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You need to use the SMS plugin within the

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   // Your plugin use here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
if(window.SMS) window.SMS.listSMS(filter,function(data){
    if(Array.isArray(data)){
      var sms = data[i];
      console.log(sms);
      $scope.article = sms;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve "SMS is not defined", you need to add `declare var SMS: any;` before`@Component({ ... })`.

Then, to list SMSs, you must extract all values from the JSON (your `data` is in a JSON).
To do this, you just need to add `JSON.stringify(data);` and delete `function` before `data` like that :

```
if(SMS) SMS.listSMS(filter, (data)=>{
JSON.stringify(data);
 if(Array.isArray(data)) {
    for(var data in data) {
        this.msg = ListSms[data].address;
    }
}
},Error=>{}),
```

So, `this.msg` have now all of the smss.